# Error during Building an APK file in Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: android, apk, build.gradle

Couple of days ago, I upgraded my Android Studio, and now I am facing a problem.

Actually I am trying to build an APK file from my project to test my app on a real device and when I click at **Build--> Build Apk** then I receive couple of errors in Message Gradle Build. I don't know why these errors are coming please elaborate on the reason as well.

**Errors**

1. **Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:**
   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/VolleyError;
2. **Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.**
   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

**build.gradle file**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }

    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dovezeal.gapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

    }

}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    // Volley
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    //compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    /* compile files('libs/com.mcxiaoke.volley library-1.0.0.jar')*/


    // RecyclerView
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'

    // A simple way to define and render UI specs on top of your Android UI.
    compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'

    compile files('libs/library-1.0.0.jar')

    // YouTube Player
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

    // GOSN
   /* compile files('libs/gson-2.2.3.jar')*/




}
```

**Edit - 1**
As janki gadhiya said in her comment below, to change `minifyEnabled true` and try adding `multiDexEnabled true` under defaultConfig 
with these changes both errors above are gone, but now this following error is coming up.

3. **Error:Execution failed for task:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'**
   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/Request$Priority.class

Comment: change `minifyEnabled true` and try adding `multiDexEnabled true`  under `defaultConfig`.

Comment: @jankigadhiya Thanks for help! please check my Edit-1 section in my question as well and please explain the actual reason of these errors

Answer (score 29, accepted):

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
}

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.dovezeal.gapp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
//compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

// as you already compiled gradle for volley here

compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

// RecyclerView
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'org.lucasr.dspec:dspec:0.1.1'

// you don't need this so comment the below line.
//compile files('libs/library-1.0.0.jar')

// YouTube Player
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')

}
```

> Edit : Explanations

**Your errors 1 - 2** : mean you are having more than 65,000 methods in your project, so I told you to set `multiDexEnable true`.

**Your error 3** : means you're having more than one library having the implementation for the class `Request$Priority.class`, so the compiler is confused which to choose. So it is showing the **error Duplicate entry**. This will be solved by `packaging options`, this will let you use duplicate files.

Comment: i tried your solution for error-3 but nothing happened and the same error is coming what am i doing wrong??

Comment: Are you having volley in your `libs` folder ??

Comment: yes i have volley in my `libs` folder named as `library-1.0.0`

Comment: That's the problem you are compiling it as gradle dependency and adding to libs, This will duplicate the library as well as methods. Simply remove `library-1.0.0.jar`  for `libs`, Then sync, clean and rebuild the project. See my edit..!! **Comment or remove the compile line `compile files('libs/library-1.0.0.jar')` from dependencies as can be seen in my edit..!!**

Comment: Thanks for your help, finally it worked and i really appreciate your help. Please tell me one more thing that is it must to remove the `jar` file from the `libs` folder, isn't it enough to just comment the including statement for that lilbrary??

Comment: yes it's enough, just to comment.. But better to remove jar also to escape the confusion.

Comment: yes i guess it right to remove the `jar` because if did not remove the file form folder then it gives me the same error and when i remove the file then it worked and generate the APK, well !! Thanks again :D

Comment: ok i accept the answer and voting is not working for me because of Reputations i will do it later and you can vote up for my question if you want

Comment: i'm having error 3 ,i have  added packing  options ..Still  error is  there.. can you  help me..  My  error --Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult.class

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your build gradle

```
    dexOptions {
            incremental true
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"    
}



packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also getting the same error. When adding the 
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
but it is removed when i do as follow:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'**
```

and in BuildVarient use **debugging mode**.

I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

while updating firebase any google play services then try to update all the libraries. this worked for me. hope it works in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

Bit late to answer but I faced the same issue.

I was able to rectify it using `multiDexEnabled` -> `true`
and used packaging options in build.gradle, post the changes .apk got installed successfully.

Syntax:

```
defaultConfig {  
    ....  
    ....  
    multiDexEnabled true  
}  

packagingOptions {  
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'  
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'  
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'  
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'  
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'  
}  
buildTypes {  
    ...  
    ...  
}
```

Hope it helps.